# Emberjs - Uncaught TypeError: Attempting to register an unknown factory: `store:main`

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm going through the tutorial for TodoMVC on Embers website and have gotten some errors along the way. The first was:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot call `compile` without the template compiler loaded. Please load `ember-template-compiler.js` prior to calling `compile`.
```

Which I solved by loading the mentioned script, but I then got an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Attempting to register an unknown factory: `store:main`
```

I've went through the Github issues (https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2988) for Ember and a solution was to include the following in the applications logic:

```
Todos.Store = DS.Store.extend();
```

But that caused the app to not load anymore (ironically without errors).

I'm using Ember v1.10, has anyone ran into this before with this version and can help?

I've installed via Bower:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "~1.10.0",
    "ember-data": "~0.0.14"
  }
```

And below is how my scripts are loaded:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ember/ember.debug.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/application.js"></script>
```

Would appreciate the help on learning a JS framework

Comment: Should I just go down one version to 1.9? Would that help solve the issue at all?

Comment: Hmm nope, version 1.9 and ember-data v1.0.0-beta.14 also give me the same error. I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here it seems, could someone advise as I'm not sure?

Comment: I reinstalled Ember from bower and it seems they did some updates where ember.debug.js is not available anymore and the addition for ember-template-compiler.js is not needed to be referenced. However I get a different error `Uncaught Error: Attempting to inject an unknown injection: store:main`